# Binding an array to an listbox so that it shows up outside of runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, listbox

Is there anyway to bind an array created in the C# portion of the code to a ListBox so that it shows up at design time?

Something like

XAML

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyStrings}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text={Binding} />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

C#

```
public string[] MyStrings = new string[] {"A", "B", "C"};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Runtime DataContext will also work in design mode. All you need to do is extract out code in separate ViewModel *(that's what MVVM pattern recommends as well)* with array declared over there and simply bind DataContext to ViewModel.

***XAML:***

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <StackPanel>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyStrings}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

***ViewModel:***

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
{    
    string[] myStrings = new string[] { "A", "B", "C" };
    public string[] MyStrings
    {
        get
        {
            return myStrings;
        }
    }
}
```

***Designer:***

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a custom type first to store data as its properties, something like this:

```
public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

then create a list using the type, like this:

```
List<Student> list1 = new List<Student>()
{
    new Student() { Name = "Bob", Age = 12 },
    new Student() { Name = "John", Age = 30 },
};
```

in XMAL, do this:

```
  <Grid>
        <ListBox x:Name="myList" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="2">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>

    </Grid>
```

lastly at run time, initial myList DataContext like this:

```
myList.DataContext = list1;
```